# Excel Mac how to create a CommandBarPopup object type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/hilkoc/vbaDeveloper) presumably very cool bit of code that presumably works out of the box on Windows to work on a Mac. I think I'm 99% there, but the Mac is unhappy with the way it's adding menus to the UI. The original code that the Mac doesn't like is this:

```
Public Sub createMenu()
    Dim rootMenu As CommandBarPopup

    'Add the top-level menu to the ribbon Add-ins section
    Set rootMenu = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
    Before:=10, _
    Temporary:=True)
    rootMenu.caption = MENU_TITLE
```

which throws a type mismatch error on the `Set` line. After a fair bit of fiddling to try and figure out what's happening, I've gotten to this:

```
Dim rootMenuBar As CommandBar
Dim rootMenu As Object

'Add the top-level menu to the ribbon Add-ins section
'Set rootMenu = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
'Before:=10, _
'Temporary:=True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
deleteMenu
Set rootMenuBar = CommandBars.Add _
    (name:=MENU_TITLE, position:=msoBarBottom, Temporary:=True)

Set rootMenu = rootMenuBar.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
With rootMenu
    .BeginGroup = True
    .caption = MENU_TITLE
    .Tag = MENU_TITLE
End With
```

which almost works, but the problem is, `rootMenu` is a `CommandBarControl` object, not a `CommandBarPopup` object, which is what the rest of the code expects. The [MS Docs for CommandBarPopup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarpopup) claim that you can use the `FindControl` method to return a `CommandBarPopup`, so I tried this:

```
With rootMenuBar
    .Controls.Add (msoControlPopup)
End With

Set rootMenu = rootMenuBar.FindControl(Type:=msoControlPopup)
```

But no dice: it's still returning a `CommandBarControl` object. Any idea how I can get it to make a `CommandBarPopup` object?

**NB**: I guess The Right Way to do this is to redo the UI using the Fluent ribbon stuff, but ... that's a much larger project than I'm looking to take on right now.

Comment: I don't use the Mac version of Excel, but your first code works fine in my Windows version.  You didn't say which version you're using, but I did a quick search on Google and it looks like you can't customize the menu on Excel 2016 for the Mac.  So you may have to customize the ribbon by modifying the CustumUI part of the workbook's XML.

Comment: Thanks @Domenic. This is Office 365 (Microsoft Excel for Mac version 16.49). My 2nd and 3rd examples both _do_ work to modify the menu bar, they're just returning the "wrong" type, and I'm hoping to figure out a way to fix that, rather than changing everywhere else in the code to deal with the different type.